# Get only required arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get only required keys for an array from another array as below.

```
    $list = array();
    $arrKeys = array("id", "name");
    foreach ($_SESSION['bArray'] as $i => $m) {
        if(count(array_intersect(array_keys($m), $arrKeys)) > 0) {
            $list[$i] = $m;
        }
    }
```

But for the `$list`, it always contains `$m`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `$arrKeys` to have keys (rather than values) that match those you wish to keep, you can use [`array_intersect_key`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key) to do what you want:

```
$list = array();
$arrKeys = array("id" => 0, "name" => 0);
foreach ($_SESSION['bArray'] as $i => $m) {
    $intersect = array_intersect_key($m, $arrKeys);
    if (count($intersect)) {
        $list[$i] = $intersect;
    }
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/SWD2p)